# Digilocker Requester API endpoints

Tags: javascript

Has anyone integrated/tested the Digilocker Requestor API? If yes can someone explain parameter ***hmac*** needed for the API endpoints.

According to the specifications:

```css
ts: Provide  a  timestamp  value  in  UNIX  (or  POSIX)  format  in  IST  
time  zone  in seconds. This timestamp value must not be older than 30 minutes

hmac: Provide   SHA-256   encrypted   value   of   the   client   secret, 
client id and ts parameters  above  concatenated  in  this  sequence 
(client  secret, clientid, ts). The hmac parameter is used  by DigiLocker 
to ensure the data integrity and authentication of the request. Use the 
Client Secret Key generated during the application registration process
on Partners Portal as the client secret.
```

I can't seem to get a correct response on Postman with all the necessary parameters. I have a client ID and secret key with me.

***What I did:*** I wrote the details - client id, secret, timestamp as a comma-separated list used an online SHA-256 hash calculator tool and passed in as the hmac parameter.

Also tried integrating the digilocker **Fetch from digilocker** widget but received 208 Unauthorized response on clicking the button.

Need some help on this subject.

Comment: That's a really bad documentation. It's missing some crucial parts, for instance what separator to use or how to encode the hash. Do the docs say something about that specific return code or is there a response body with additional info?

Comment: https://partners.digitallocker.gov.in/requester.php
This is the pdf for the requester specification. It gives a response body and return code examples for different wrong cases but none of them match. For example it says 
`Sample Error Response: HTTP/1.1 400Bad RequestContent-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8{"error":"invalid_parameter","error_description":"Timestampparameter ismissingor invalid"
`
But it returns a 404 not found error to me so I can't even figure out what is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use any separator for contacting the values of clientSecret, ClientID and TS, directly contact them
After you have contacted the parameters create a hash value, not any hmac
I used an online tool to verify https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html

`let data = clientSecret + clientId + timestamp;`
`let hashValue = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(data).digest("hex");`

Answer (score 0):

Above answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/67427086/2169641) worked for me. Digilocker expects the clientSecret, clientId and timestamp concatenated without any separators.
Simple Hex encoded Sha256 encryption of `const message = clientSecret + clientId + now;` works.